# Удаление всех файлов из каталога кроме нужных

Tags: изображения, php, html

Добрый день.

На сервере лежит директория *img*, в этом каталоге загруженные изображения для обработки, расширение файлов, которое туда загружают пользователи .jpg .Jpg .png .PNG .gif и т.д.

При запуске мной кода:

```
if (file_exists('./img'))
foreach (glob('./img/*') as $file)
unlink($file); 
  echo("Файлы каталога успешно удалены, обновите страницу");
```

удаляются все файлы в директории *img*.

Вопрос: *как изменить этот код что бы не удалялись указанные мной файлы, например:*

1. load.gif
2. .htaccess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (file_exists('./img')) {

  foreach (glob('./img/*') as $file)
  {
    if ($file!='.htaccess') unlink($file); 
  }

  echo("Файлы каталога успешно удалены, обновите страницу");

}
```

Примерно так

Comment: Работает, спасибо.

Comment: На случай, если сохранить нужно несколько файлов:

    $keep = explode( ',', 'load.gif,.htaccess,nestirat.jpg'); // нужные имена через запятую
    ...
    // а в цикле
        if( !in_array( $file, $keep)) unlink( $file);

Answer (score 0):

```
if (file_exists('./img/mini_logo')) {
  include('db.php');
  $query = 'SELECT img FROM zayav'; 
  $res = mysql_query( $query ); 
  $img = array();
  while ( $item = mysql_fetch_array($res)) {
    $img3 = $item['img'];
    $way="./img/mini_logo/$img3.png";
    $img[] = $way;
  }
  foreach (glob('./img/mini_logo/*') as $file)
  {
     if( !in_array( $file, $img)) unlink($file); 
  }
  echo "<script>history.go(-1);alert( 'Все ненужные файлы очищены!');</script>";
}
```

Вот мой код. В базе имена файлов без расширения, они ссылаются на реальные изображения в папке. Ставили задачу, очищать папку от мусора (старых изображений) но что бы используемые файлы не были затронуты. Вдруг кому будет полезно.